# Can I create a circle label with a leader in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cartography, labeling

I want to create a circle label with a leader using the standard Maplex labelling engine and symbology.   Only 1 or 2 digit numbers will appear in the label.

I can easily make square or rectangular label with a leader but not a circle.  Is i possible.

Here as an example![enter image description here of what i need:

[image]

Comment: Based on experimentation and this [forum post](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/49224), I'm going to say no, it's not possible with *just* Maplex labels.  I did find [several](http://www.bgcarto.com/leadered-symbols-in-arcmap/) [workarounds](http://www.cartotalk.com/index.php?showtopic=2901) (among others, including having the layer in twice with two label symbologies), but none of them are simple/quick/completely effective..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an existing [ArcGIS Idea](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=08730000000880xAAA) titled **Circular callout backgrounds** to:

> Add circular text callout backgrounds in addition to the default
>   rectangular box callout backgrounds.

If you have not already done so, I recommend that you add your vote to that.